# Can provideTags be used with queryFn

Tags: redux-toolkit

Can providesTags (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#providestags) be used with queryFn or with query only?

Comment: It's important to not just post the question, but to also include a description of what the code or question does and why you are suggesting or ask it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the question, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question.

Comment: @DSDmark this is purely a "yes" or "no" question and does not need any more detail for someone with domain knowledge to answer it. It is not explicitly shown in the documentation, since `query` vs `queryFn` has nothing to do with `invalidateTags`/`provideTags` as a feature. So they are just asking for the clarification on "can I do this?" and the answer is "yes" - there is really not anything to add from either side to have clear communication about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `providesTags` can be used with `queryFn`.

Comment: Please don't just provide the solution without any further explanation. Instead, try to provide more context about the situation in which the question was asked, and explain how the solution solves the problem. If the explanation for the solution is not too long, consider writing a comment instead of posting the answer directly, @phry.

Comment: @DSDmark the user was asking a question that can only be answered with "yes" or "no". There is literally nothing different between using `providesTags` with `queryFn` or without it. There is no code difference (apart from using `queryFn` instead of `query`, which they are obviously doing or they would not ask the question, since `queryFn` is an alternative to `query` and you have to use one or the other). Tbh., they could also have spent a moment to just try it instead of asking and it would have worked.